# HTML5 video and Video.js: No playback in Firefox depending on order of sources

Tags: firefox, video, html5-video, video.js

I’m using Video.js 4.9. I did not have a chance to verify whether the problem described below exists with a pure HTML5 player as well:

My video plays fine in recent versions of all major browsers on Mac OS, in Safari on iOS 7 and in IE11 on Windows 7.

But in Firefox 35 on Windows 7, all I get is a black rectangle and this error message:

> The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because
>   the video used features your browser did not support.

**The video does play in FF 35 on Win 7 when I change the order of the source tags** and put webm before mp4. But AFAIK, not putting the mp4 tag first may cause trouble in (older versions of?) Chrome and Safari.

What should I do about this?

This is my code. Most of the JavaScript code makes the webpage responsive.

```
<!-- header -->
<link href="../../video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../../video-js/video.dev.js"></script>

<!-- video tag in body -->
<video id="mobile_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" autoplay controls preload="none" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="tgm.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="tgm.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="tgm.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>

<!-- JS code directly below -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  videojs.autoSetup();

    videojs('mobile_video').ready(function(){
      //log all of the default videojs options
      console.log(this.options()); 

       // Store the video object
      var myPlayer = this, id = myPlayer.id();
      // Make up an aspect ratio
      var aspectRatio = 450/800; 

      function resizeVideoJS(){
        var width = document.getElementById(id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
        myPlayer.width(width).height( width * aspectRatio );

      }

      // Initialize resizeVideoJS()
      resizeVideoJS();
      // Then on resize call resizeVideoJS()
      window.onresize = resizeVideoJS; 
    });
  </script>
```

**EDIT**

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940299/source-order-of-videos-affects-browser-playback?rq=1). Someone solved a very similar problem by including the attribute data-setup='{}'. This has always been in my code.

Comment: What codecs are used in the MP4?

Comment: @misterben, it's H.264. In HandBrake, it's called H.264 (x264). I start from the Devices/Universal preset, then I use these settings: 
- av. bitrate: 220 kbit/s 
- 2-pass 
- web optimized 
- fps 25 constant 
- aac core, mono, 64 kbit/s

Comment: I presume this is the HTML5 tech? I've heard of h.264 playback problems in Firefox but haven't dug into that myself. Try using the baseline h.264 profile if you're not already, maybe try ffmpeg instead of handbrake too. Otherwise a dirty hack like setting the source order depending on the user agent may be in order.

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved an issue with no mp4 playback in Chrome or Firefox (played fine in IE) in a page with 16 videos in modals (bootstrap 3) after discovering the frame rates of all the videos must be identical.  I had 6 videos at 25fps and 12 at 29.97fps...  after rendering all to 25fps versions, everything ran smooth across all browsers.  No need for multi format videos any longer as well.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more?